# How to fire click event of the LinkButton in gridview and Show PopUp window in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have tried to build one **gridview with dynamic columns** based the data source **using the template fields** in asp.net through code behind.

For that, to implement we have developed one class `DynamicTemplate` which implements the `ITemplate` interface. In that template fields i have inserted the `LinkButton` in each cell and when i click that cell link button i need to show the one Popup with selected cell value.

[For Detailed Sample Please download from this link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=C55C4D7B56FE99BB!231&authkey=!AOi6B54Fkj-YYmE&ithint=file,.rar)

For that I have created one Default.asxp page and wrote the following.

```
  public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataTable dt;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                GenateGridView();

        }

        private void GenateGridView()
        {
            TemplateField tempField;
            DynamicTemplate dynTempItem;
            LinkButton lnkButton;
            Label label;

            GridView gvDynamicArticle = new GridView();

            gvDynamicArticle.Width = Unit.Pixel(500);
            gvDynamicArticle.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(0);
            gvDynamicArticle.Caption = "<div>Default Grid</div>";
            gvDynamicArticle.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            DataTable data = getBindingData();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                tempField = new TemplateField();
                dynTempItem = new DynamicTemplate(ListItemType.AlternatingItem);

                lnkButton = new LinkButton();

                lnkButton.ID = string.Format("lnkButton{0}", i);
                lnkButton.Visible = true;

                string ColumnValue = data.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                tempField.HeaderText = ColumnValue;

                if (ColumnValue == "EmpName")
                {
                    label = new Label();

                    label.ID = string.Format("Label{0}", i);
                    dynTempItem.AddControl(label, "Text", ColumnValue);
                    label.Width = 100;
                }
                else
                {
                    dynTempItem.AddControl(lnkButton, "Text", ColumnValue);
                    lnkButton.Click += lnkButton_Click;
                }
                tempField.ItemTemplate = dynTempItem;
                gvDynamicArticle.Columns.Add(tempField);
                //////grdUserPivotDateTwo.Columns.Add(tempField);
            }

            gvDynamicArticle.DataSource = data;
            gvDynamicArticle.DataBind();

            divContainer.Controls.Add(gvDynamicArticle);

        }

        void lnkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // showing cell values in popUp here.. 
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('cell clicked')");
        }


        private DataTable getBindingData()
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmpName"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Monday"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TuesDay"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("WednesDay"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ThursDay"));

            dt.Rows.Add("EmpOne", "p", "p", "p", "a");
            dt.Rows.Add("EmpTwo", "p", "a", "p", "p");
            dt.Rows.Add("EmpThree", "p", "p", "p", "a");
            dt.Rows.Add("EmpFour", "p", "a", "p", "p");
            dt.Rows.Add("EmpFive", "p", "p", "p", "a");
            dt.Rows.Add("EmpSix", "a", "p", "p", "p");

            return dt;

        }



    }
```

and corresponding `DynamicTemplate` class is

```
public class DynamicTemplate : System.Web.UI.ITemplate
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType templateType;
    System.Collections.Hashtable htControls = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
    System.Collections.Hashtable htBindPropertiesNames = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
    System.Collections.Hashtable htBindExpression = new System.Collections.Hashtable();

    public DynamicTemplate(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType type)
    {
        templateType = type;
    }

    public void AddControl(WebControl wbControl, String BindPropertyName, String BindExpression)
    {
        htControls.Add(htControls.Count, wbControl);
        htBindPropertiesNames.Add(htBindPropertiesNames.Count, BindPropertyName);
        htBindExpression.Add(htBindExpression.Count, BindExpression);

    }

    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        PlaceHolder ph = new PlaceHolder();

        for (int i = 0; i < htControls.Count; i++)
        {

            //clone control 
            Control cntrl = CloneControl((Control)htControls[i]);

            switch (templateType)
            {
                case ListItemType.Header:
                    break;
                case ListItemType.Item:
                    ph.Controls.Add(cntrl);
                    break;
                case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                    ph.Controls.Add(cntrl);
                    ph.DataBinding += new EventHandler(Item_DataBinding);
                    break;
                case ListItemType.Footer:
                    break;
            }
        }
        ph.DataBinding += new EventHandler(Item_DataBinding);

        container.Controls.Add(ph);

    }
    public void Item_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PlaceHolder ph = (PlaceHolder)sender;
        GridViewRow ri = (GridViewRow)ph.NamingContainer;
        for (int i = 0; i < htControls.Count; i++)
        {
            if (htBindPropertiesNames[i].ToString().Length > 0)
            {
                Control tmpCtrl = (Control)htControls[i];
                String item1Value = (String)DataBinder.Eval(ri.DataItem, htBindExpression[i].ToString());
                Control ctrl = ph.FindControl(tmpCtrl.ID);

                Type t = ctrl.GetType();
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(htBindPropertiesNames[i].ToString());

                pi.SetValue(ctrl, item1Value.ToString(), null);
            }

        }



    }

    private Control CloneControl(System.Web.UI.Control src_ctl)
    {
        Type t = src_ctl.GetType();
        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        Control dst_ctl = (Control)obj;
        PropertyDescriptorCollection src_pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(src_ctl);
        PropertyDescriptorCollection dst_pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(dst_ctl);

        for (int i = 0; i < src_pdc.Count; i++)
        {

            if (src_pdc[i].Attributes.Contains(DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute.Content))
            {

                object collection_val = src_pdc[i].GetValue(src_ctl);
                if ((collection_val is IList) == true)
                {
                    foreach (object child in (IList)collection_val)
                    {
                        Control new_child = CloneControl(child as Control);
                        object dst_collection_val = dst_pdc[i].GetValue(dst_ctl);
                        ((IList)dst_collection_val).Add(new_child);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dst_pdc[src_pdc[i].Name].SetValue(dst_ctl, src_pdc[i].GetValue(src_ctl));
            }
        }

        return dst_ctl;

    }
}
```

Here the Data showing in `gridview` is fine. Here ***the Issues*** are **when i click on the linkButton the page reloads and no grid is displaying after the postback**.

second issue is, for **`LinkButton` the `Click Event` is not firing**.

Please provide me the help full information/Sample to show the modal window when we click on the linkButton of the gridview.

Comment: Why are you performing GUI stuff in the code behind? Shouldn't that be done on the declarative .aspx page?

It's also a good idea to have logic that should happen on the client side such as opening popup windows be done purely with JavaScript since it doesn't need to involve server side interaction.

Comment: the columns were build based on condition and no.of columns to dispaly may vary. i need to save the values of the popup window after some changes.that's why i trying to use server side event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax model popup expender.

Design a panel with your fields and use the model popup expender to display that popup

This link has the sample of it

www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

and in your link button click
you have to use show method to open popup

Comment: use popup window show method because page postback is happening here

Comment: Here the main issue is not showing the popup, before trying to show popup, when i click on linkbutton of gridview it is reloading to new page and the click event is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            GenateGridView();

    }
```

this code is generating a gridview only if it is not a postback, but when you click a linkbutton a postpack occurs and that's the reason why gridview doesnt show again when you click on the linkbutton.

add the following code(additional else part included to your if code) to show gridview when you click lnkButton

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            GenateGridView();
        else
        {
            string ctrlName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET").Trim();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrlName))
            {
                if (ctrlName.StartsWith("lnkButton"))
                {
                    GenateGridView();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: thank you for your code, i used the above code but here (ctrlName.StartsWith("lnkButton")) always returns 'false'  so the "GenarateGridView" method didn't call and displaying empty page

Answer (score 0):

It will be a good choice to use **CommandName** property for the **linkbutton** on the Gridview and give it a specfic name and in the code file and exactly work with it in **RowCommand event of your GridView** as following in this example :

**first here is the .aspx file :**

```
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewStudents" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridViewStudents_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stud_ID" Visible="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelStudID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Stud_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FKFather_ID" Visible="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelFkFatherID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fk_Father_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelStudName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Stud_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Class Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelRowlevelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Stud_Level_Row_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Stud_ID") %>' CommandName="Remove" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>

<div style="direction: ltr">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="Labelpopupmessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Buttonaccept" runat="server" Text="نعم" OnClick="Buttonaccept_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Buttoncancel" runat="server" Text="لا" OnClick="Buttoncancel_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="ModalPopupExtenderStudent" PopupControlID="ButtonSubmit" TargetControlID="HiddenField1" CancelControlID="Buttoncancel">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
</div>
```

**and here is the code implementation of my illustration :**

```
        protected void GridViewStudents_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.CommandName == "Remove")
                    {
                       // I stored the ID of the selected Student I want to delete in a viewstate.
                                    ViewState.Add("DeletedStudDetailID",Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
 ModalpopupExtender.Show();
                    }

                 }

// Here in the accept delete button I used that code ..
        protected void Buttonaccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ViewState["DeletedStudDetailID"] != null)
                {
                    StudentDetail StudDet = Data.StudentDetails.Single(SD => SD.Fk_Stud_ID == Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["DeletedStudDetailID"]));
                    Data.StudentDetails.DeleteOnSubmit(StudDet);
                    Student Stud = Data.Students.Single(S => S.Stud_ID == Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["DeletedStudDetailID"]));
                    Data.Students.DeleteOnSubmit(Stud);
                    Data.SubmitChanges();
                }
                this.ResultMessage = "Delete Done Sucessfully !!";
            }
            catch
            {
                this.ErrorMessage = "Delete operation disordered !!";
            }
            finally
            {
                ModalPopExtender.Hide();
            }

        }
```

I hope it helps in your issue and I wish you a happy day :) !!

Comment: Thank you for the Sample, but here i need to build the Template field dynamically, to show all the dates except holidays in a month based on employee timings. that's why i took runtime gridview with templates.

Answer (score 0):

First, your GridView will be created when calling `GenateGridView` method, so you have to call this method everytime you do post back, then your Page_Load should be

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GenateGridView();
}
```

Second, I would present you the other way to add LinkButton to GridView dynamically.
I modified your **GenateGridView** to just add only label into **DynamicTemplate**, also add this line **`gvDynamicArticle.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gvDynamicArticle_RowDataBound);`** to handle adding LinkButton.

```
private void GenateGridView()
{
    TemplateField tempField;
    DynamicTemplate dynTempItem;
    Label label;

    GridView gvDynamicArticle = new GridView();

    gvDynamicArticle.Width = Unit.Pixel(500);
    gvDynamicArticle.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(0);
    gvDynamicArticle.Caption = "<div>Default Grid</div>";
    gvDynamicArticle.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    gvDynamicArticle.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gvDynamicArticle_RowDataBound);
    DataTable data = getBindingData();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        tempField = new TemplateField();
        dynTempItem = new DynamicTemplate(ListItemType.AlternatingItem);

        string ColumnValue = data.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        tempField.HeaderText = ColumnValue;

        label = new Label();

        label.ID = string.Format("Label{0}", i);
        dynTempItem.AddControl(label, "Text", ColumnValue);
        label.Width = 100;

        tempField.ItemTemplate = dynTempItem;
        gvDynamicArticle.Columns.Add(tempField);
    }

    gvDynamicArticle.DataSource = data;
    gvDynamicArticle.DataBind();

    divContainer.Controls.Add(gvDynamicArticle);
}
```

I implement like this in **RowDataBound** event handler of the GridView to add LinkButton and hide the Label which we added it before:

```
protected void gvDynamicArticle_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    for (int j = 1; j < e.Row.Cells.Count; j++)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lnkButton = new LinkButton();
            lnkButton.ID = string.Format("lnkButton{0}{1}", e.Row.DataItemIndex, j);
            lnkButton.Click += new EventHandler(lnkButton_Click);

            Label tempLabel = e.Row.FindControl("Label" + j) as Label;
            lnkButton.Text = tempLabel.Text;
            lnkButton.CommandArgument = tempLabel.Text;

            tempLabel.Visible = false;

            e.Row.Cells[j].Controls.Add(lnkButton);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also set any value to **CommandArgument** of LinkButton, then you can show it in the alert.

Final, seems you want to show some value in the alert, you may code like this

```
public void lnkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // showing cell values in popUp here.. 
    LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('cell clicked, value " + lnk.CommandArgument + "')", true);
}
```