# linkButton Click Event in Grid View not firing when adding though Bound Fields in a loop in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hi,Here i am trying to implement the linkButton click event in a
gridview through code behind using the BoundField Class in gridview.
when i trying to add the individual BoundField values Directly to grid
as a column in page_Load and binding the linkbutton in
RowDataBoundEvent of the row of cell with linkbutton click event, it
is firing the linkButton Click event well with the following code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{

          BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
           bfield.HeaderText = "EmpName";
           bfield.DataField = "EmpName";
           gridView.Columns.Add(bfield);

           BoundField bfield1 = new BoundField();
           bfield1.HeaderText = "Monday";
           bfield1.DataField = "Monday";
           gridView.Columns.Add(bfield1);
}
```

and in on RowDataBound Event i have wrote

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton lnkViews = new LinkButton();
            lnkViews.ID = "lnkViews";
            lnkViews.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["Monday"].ToString();
            lnkViews.Click += new EventArgs(linkButton_ClickAction);
            e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(lnkViews);


        }
    }

protected void linkButton_ClickAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 LinkButton lnkView = (sender as LinkButton); 
GridViewRow row = (lnkView.NamingContainer as GridViewRow); 
string id = lnkView.CommandArgument; 
string name = row.Cells[0].Text; this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
 }
```

But when i trying to add the above BoundFields by looping based on the
table columns count like this, in page_Load event, the event is not
firing.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{ 
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();

           dtTable= BindGrid();

           BoundField boundField;
           for (int i = 0; i < dtTable.Columns.Count; i++)
           {
               string ColumnValue = dtTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                boundField = new BoundField();
                boundField.HeaderText = ColumnValue;
                boundField.DataField = ColumnValue;
                gridView.Columns.Add(boundField);
           }
}
```

when we creating the BoudnField event using the above code in a loop
based on dataSource columns count, it doesn't firing linkbutton event. why?

Comment: have you tried row created event instead of rowdatabound

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding you are trying to form grid dynamically.

One thing is bound fields will not support for bubbled events. So better replace them with  template fields that will meets your requirement.

You need to assign click event in InstantiateIn method by defining ITemplate interface.
OnRowDataBound event doesn't comes into picture.

below is example for your reference.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1001702.aspx

Comment: i already tried to do this same thing with as you suggested above, in that also i have the same problem, becase i could not aware how to solve this problem in itemtemplates , i came to this method, if you can please see the link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613303/how-to-fire-click-event-of-the-linkbutton-in-gridview-and-show-popup-window-in-a

Comment: Yes, you cannot assign click event directly in InstantiateIn due to it is separate class and page variables can't be accessble.
Try to do it by java script. add a button out side of grid and set display to "None", assign a function with onclick attribute in InstantiateIn for link button in that function assign ID/Number to the hidden field, call the button click event from that function. Write the code in button click event which you intended to do in link button click event, use hidden variable value instead of command argument/text.
This might be hectic but definitely works.